# Is it posible with InstagramApiSharp to post data to instagram?

Tags: c#, instagram-api

I want to know if it is posible to post data to instagram like a picture or some text by using InstagramApiSharp

I have tried looking though google, but didnt find any answer about it

Comment: Have you read their [documentation](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/wiki)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [the project](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp) description says, it supports almost all features.
It does support photo uploads and posting.